# R's data.table Truncating Bits?

Tags: r, data.table

So I'm a huge `data.table` fan in R.  I use it almost all the time but have come across a situation in which it won't work for me at all.  I have a package (internal to my company) that uses R's `double` to store the value of an unsigned 64 bit integer whose bit sequence corresponds to some fancy encoding.  This package works very nicely everywhere except data.table.  I found that if I aggregate on a column of this data that I lose a large number of my unique values.  My only guess here is that `data.table` is truncating bits in some kind of weird `double` optimization.

Can anyone confirm that this is the case?  Is this simply a bug?

Below see a reproduction of the issue and comparison to the package I currently must use but want to avoid with a passion (`dplyr`).

```
temp <- structure(list(obscure_math = c(6.95476896592629e-309, 6.95476863436446e-309, 
6.95476743245288e-309, 6.95476942182375e-309, 6.95477149408563e-309, 
6.95477132830476e-309, 6.95477132830476e-309, 6.95477149408562e-309, 
6.95477174275702e-309, 6.95476880014538e-309, 6.95476896592647e-309, 
6.95476896592647e-309, 6.95476900737172e-309, 6.95476900737172e-309, 
6.95476946326899e-309, 6.95476958760468e-309, 6.95476958760468e-309, 
6.95477020928318e-309, 6.95477124541406e-309, 6.95476859291965e-309, 
6.95476875870014e-309, 6.95476904881676e-309, 6.95476904881676e-309, 
6.95476904881676e-309, 6.95476909026199e-309, 6.95476909026199e-309, 
6.95476909026199e-309, 6.95476909026199e-309, 6.9547691317072e-309, 
6.9547691317072e-309, 6.9547691317072e-309, 6.9547691317072e-309, 
6.9547691317072e-309, 6.9547691317072e-309, 6.9547691317072e-309, 
6.9547691317072e-309, 6.9547691317072e-309, 6.9547691317072e-309, 
6.9547691317072e-309, 6.9547691317072e-309, 6.95477211576406e-309, 
6.95476880014538e-309, 6.95476880014538e-309, 6.95476880014538e-309, 
6.95476892448104e-309, 6.95476880014538e-309, 6.95476892448105e-309, 
6.9547689659263e-309, 6.95476913170719e-309, 6.95476933893334e-309
)), .Names = "obscure_math", class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))

dt_collapsed <- temp[, .(count=.N), by=obscure_math]
nrow(dt_collapsed) == length(unique(temp$obscure_math))

setDF(temp)
dplyr_collapsed <- temp %>% group_by(obscure_math) %>% summarise(count=n())
nrow(dplyr_collapsed) == length(unique(temp$obscure_math))
```

Comment: I can replicate this on data.table 1.9.6. `aggregate` gives 26 rows as well, but `data.table` gives 21. Using `by=as.character(obscure_math)` also gives the correct 26 rows

Comment: I can replicate too using v1.9.7

Comment: These are very small numbers admittedly, probably below typical rounding error.

Comment: @thelatemail I'm not sure that should matter though.  The package shouldn't be changing the value of the user's data in such an operation.  It's very opaque that the value of the `by` variable should be changed at all.  My guess is this has something to do with optimizing for a radix sort but no one should expect a loss of precision (and in this case total unusability) from such an operation.

Comment: We recommend using `bit64::integer64` for 64-bit integers (instead of double). See `?setNumericRounding` (and example) for why we round off last 2 bytes. There's an issue filed in relation to this (but w.r.t. ordering a data.table, not grouping), but we've not had time to get to how best to handle it yet, [#1642](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1642).

Comment: @Arun Wow.  That blows my mind that you are rounding off the last 16 bits of all doubles by default on these operations.  That is a terrible design decision as far as I can tell.  You're making awfully big assumptions about what constitutes "plenty of digits".  Disappointing.  Please add as an answer so I can accept and close this question out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update:** the default rounding feature has been removed in the [current development version of data.table (v1.9.7)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki). See installation instructions for devel version [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

This also means that you're responsible for understanding the limitations in representing floating point numbers and dealing with it.

---

data.table has been around for a long time. We used to deal with limitations in floating point representations by using a *threshold* (like base R does, e.g., `all.equal`). However it simply does not work, since it needs to be adaptive depending on how big the numbers compared are. [This series of articles](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) is an excellent read on this topic and other potential issues.

This being a recurring issue because a) people don't realise the limitations, or b) *threshold*ing did not really help their issue, meant that people kept asking here or posting on the project page.

While we reimplemented data.table's order to fast radix ordering, we took the opportunity to provide an alternative way of fixing the issue, and providing a way out if it proves undesirable (exporting `setNumericRounding`). With #1642 issue,  *ordering* probably doesn't need to have rounding of doubles (but it's not that simple, since order directly affects binary search based subsets).

The actual problem here is *grouping on floating point numbers*, even worse is such numbers as in your case. That is just a bad choice IMHO.

I can think of two ways forward:

1. When grouping on columns that are really doubles (in R, 1 is double as opposed to 1L, and those cases don't have issues) we provide a warning that the last 2 bytes are rounded off, and that people should read `?setNumericRounding`. And also suggest using `bit64::integer64`.
2. Remove the functionality of allowing *grouping* operations on really double values or force them to fix the precision to certain digits before continuing. I can't think of a valid reason why one would want to group by floating point numbers really (would love to hear from people who do).

What is very unlikely to happen is going back to *threshold*ing based checks for identifying which doubles should belong to the same group.

Just so that the Q remains answered, use `setNumericRounding(0L)`.

Comment: Thumbs-up on explicit errors when grouping is done on doubles.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thank you. I've filed [#1728](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1728). I agree that's the best way forward.

Comment: Cheers, thanks! I would suggest warnings with suggestions for grouping by doubles.  I can think of a reason a user would group on a double.  It's in my question :)

Comment: @iShouldUseAName, sorry that's *not* a valid reason. Your company's package should start using 64-bit integers (using bit64, or your own internal implementation) for that. Not misuse / play around with doubles.

Comment: @Arun The 64-bit integer is just used to hold an encoding that happens to fit in 64 bits and is for most languages usable natively.  In R it is not and bit64 simply uses double itself internally.  So I guess they are misusing them too? We will likely stick with using doubles so as to not try to integrate at C level with another package and switch to dplyr when necessary. Cheers and thanks again!

Comment: I don't know anything more about your representation that it's an encoding your company uses. In case of bit64, I know that there's no ambiguity in representing numbers as integer64 (even though they're internally doubles). E.g., `identical(3e8, 3e8*(1+.Machine$double.eps))` vs `Identical(as.integer64(3e8), as.integer64(3e8*(1+.Machine$double.eps))` -- i.e., there's no ambiguity in the next possible value.. in case of integer64 it's 3e8+1. That is definitely better. It seems like int64 package is archived since 2012.

Comment: The reason you specify for not using your package doesn't make much sense to me, but okay. But maybe you're interested in bringing int64 alive again? To continue doing what you do now would/should be the last option IMO. Sure, feel free to use whatever package you need. Best.

Comment: @Arun I think I may be struggling to convey why we are doing what we are doing.  We have code that takes certain data and creates a 64 bit encoding of it using fancy maths that allows us to aggregate data in a meaningful way.  This encoding never has integer maths performed on it.  We do some bitwise operations to encode/decode and get some other data but that's it.  To make this high performance in R we use `double` to hold these 64 bits.  All this is to say that users may choose to do things you don't expect but are perfectly valid use cases which is why I would suggest warning not limiting.

Comment: @Arun it also appears from `data.table` source code that I may be able to just add `integer64` as a class to my column and get around this while still using data.table.  Thanks again for all the great work on `data.table` and my question!